# hudson.AbortException: No files found in path with configured filemask: output.xml

Tags: jenkins, hudson, robotframework

I was running a RobotFramework script using Jenkins and everything was working fine until I accidentally wiped out my current workspace. I don't know how to restore it and now I'm getting the following error:

```
Robot results publisher started...
-Parsing output xml:
Failed!
hudson.AbortException: No files found in path C:\Users\EEMIZHA\.jenkins\jobs\3PI RF2\workspace with configured filemask: output.xml
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser$RobotParserCallable.invoke(RobotParser.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser$RobotParserCallable.invoke(RobotParser.java:54)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotParser.parse(RobotParser.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotPublisher.parse(RobotPublisher.java:217)
    at hudson.plugins.robot.RobotPublisher.perform(RobotPublisher.java:239)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Publish Robot Framework test results' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have the robot plugin installed, I've enabled a "Publish Robot Framework test results" post build action, and I'm executing a very simple Windows Batch Command as follows:

```
cd C:\Users\EEMIZHA\Documents\3PIManager\Testing\
pybot jenkinsConnectionTest.robot
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by using a custom workspace in Jenkins set to my `\path\to\test` (under Advanced Project Options/Advanced...). Run pybot command with `-d \path\to\test\output-folder` parameter and set `output-folder` as "Directory of Robot output" in Robot Framework post build action.